# Can't access to redux-toolkit state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to learn redux-toolkit but I struggle a little bit to access my data after set it.
I tried to create a registration form, once the form is filled in I set the values in my store and try to access them through a hook on another page.
However, I only get the initial state and not the values set earlier.
This is my code:

auth.ts

```
const tokenManager = new TokenManager();
const userManager = new UserManager();

export const auth = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState: {
    token: "",
    user: null
  },
  reducers: {
    get: (state) => state,
    setUser: (state, action) => {
      userManager.setUser(action.payload);
      state.user = action.payload;
    },
    setToken: (state, action) => {
      if (action.payload !== tokenManager.getToken()) {
        tokenManager.setToken(action.payload);
      }
      state.token = action.payload;
    }
  },

});

export const authActions = auth.actions;
export const authReducer = auth.reducer;
```

store.ts

```
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    auth: authReducer,
  },
});
```

useUser.ts

```
export const useUser = () => {
  return useSelector((state: any) => state.auth.user);
}
```

SignupView.tsx

```
function handleOnSubmit(values: SignupValues) {
    dispatch(authActions.setToken("ahohegogogao"));
    dispatch(authActions.setUser(values));
    navigate("/");
  }
```

When I try to access the value that useUser gives me, I end up with the initial state of my reducer but i don't understand why.
Does anyone have any idea where the problem might come from?
Thanks for your help.

------- EDIT :
Looks like I need to do that :

```
initialState: {
    token: tokenManager.getToken(),
    user: userManager.getUser()
  },
```

To be able to retrieve my state when i change the url...